# non-numeric argument to binary operator in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

This is my code below, I think it may just be a silly mistake but I have spent the last 5 days trying to find where I went wrong in my app:-

```
ui <- fluidPage(h1("Left Ventricular Hypertrophy"),
                titlePanel("Regression Model"),
                sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(

                  h3("Marginal Histogram"),
                  selectInput("marhis1", "X:", choices = unique(colnames(lvh))),
                  selectInput("marhis2", "Y:", choices = unique(colnames(lvh)), selected = "sbp"),
                  sliderInput("bin", "Bin Width:", min = 1, max = 100, value = 10),
                  h3("Box Plot"),
                  selectInput("Variable4", "llvmi or sbp:", choices = c("llvmi", "sbp")),
                  selectInput("Variable5", "Grouped by:", choices = c("sex", "card", "dgp", "surv")),

                  mainPanel(
                            h3("Marginal Histogram"),
                            plotOutput("hist"),
                            br(),
                            h3("Boxplot"),
                            plotOutput("Box")
                            )

                  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  lvh <- read.table('lvh.dat.txt', header = T)



  output$hist <- renderPlot({
  marg <- ggplot(lvh, aes(input$marhis1, input$marhis2) + geom_point() + theme_light() +
  xlab(input$marhis1) + ylab(input$marhis2))
  ggMarginal(marg, input$marhis1, input$marhis2, type = "histogram", binwidth = input$bin)
})


  output$Box <- renderPlot({
    choice2 <- data.frame(x=lvh[input$Variable4], y=lvh[input$Variable5])
    ggplot(choice2, aes(lvh[input$Variable4], lvh[input$Variable5]) + geom_boxplot() + theme_light() +
            xlab(input$Variable4) + ylab(input$Variable5))
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I keep getting an error of non-numeric argument to binary operator in both of the plots when I run app, could anyone help

Comment: This is probably too much code to wade through for anyone wanting to help. Try narrowing the problem down to something more specific. For instance, your error probably has nothing really to do with Shiny. In particular, `aes(as.character(input$marhis1), as.character(input$marhis2))` looks rather wrong to me.

Comment: Yeah i removed this, I will move the code that is causing the issue over into a smaller version

Comment: Is that better? Its really just the plots that the issues comes up with, also thanks for pointing out about code being too long, first post

Comment: It may be trying to pull input before they're selected.  You can try adding `req()` for each input within the relevant `renderPlot()` functions OR have default selections for the input OR both.

Comment: Put up a working example that can reproduce the error. I am unable to reproduce your error

Comment: Tried both and didn't work still the error persists

Comment: What do you mean user5249203, as I am running the code the error still there

Comment: Can you add some sample data so we can try reproducing the error with it?

Comment: llvmi sbp sex card dgp surv
5.17867  112  2  1  1  0
5.39291  120  1  1  1  0
4.92379  130  1  1  1  0
5.54941  139  1  1  2  0
5.88333  141  1  1  2  0
4.84763  147  1  1  1  0
5.99543  150  2  1  1  0
4.77981  150  2  2  1  0
4.83465  152  1  2  1  0
5.07140  170  1  1  1  0
4.72805  110  1  1  1  0
4.82177  144  1  1  1  0
4.01548  134  2  1  1  0
4.76053  150  2  1  1  0
5.41664  110  2  1  2  0
5.25461  140  2  1  1  0
3.84533   98  2  1  2  0
4.11098  116  1  1  1  0
4.14759  110  1  1  1  0
4.17439  120  1  1  1  0
4.18231  130  1  1  2  0

Comment: Theres a subset of the data I am using

Answer (score 2):

First, let me encourage you to always provide code samples that are easy to inspect. Since, from your comment conversation in the original post, one can see that you did not quite get what that means: Make the code snippet so that **simple copy + paste** will be enough to run into the errors you are facing.

At least four people looked at your code and everyone was immediately discouraged to invest some patience into it.

Otherwise it would have been easy to detect, that you are **just missing a parenthesis** in the part

```
ggplot(lvh, aes(input$marhis1, input$marhis2) + geom_point()
```

where it must be

```
ggplot(lvh, aes(input$marhis1, input$marhis2)) + geom_point()
```

(of course eliminating the also misplaced original closing bracket).

Edit: Same goes for the second call to `ggplot`. More on that: `ggplot` works by adding layers to the plot. That is why you have to add  (`+`) the `ggplot(...)` generated elements. Not adding options inside the call to `ggplot`.